# Weyl's Theorem and applications

Tags: lie-algebras

Consider $g$ a Lie algebra.

Prove that if $ad(g)$ is semisimples then the $ad (g)$ representation is completely reducible.

Prove:
if ad g is semi-simple, an i apply the Weyl's theorem directly to say that g is completely reducible $ad (g)$-modulus?

Comment: Hint: Look at the complexification of $\mathcal{g}$ (if necessary) and then look at the compact real form!

Comment: Not "lie algebra" but Lie algebra, like Weyl's theorem (not weyl's theorem).